# How to parse The JsonArray in windows 8.1 (for phone apps)?

Tags: arrays

1.I am trying to connect my win 8.1 phone app to my server and I succeeded and I am getting a response in JsonArray

```
private async void NavigateBtn_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            long phone =System.Convert.ToInt64(phoneNumber.Text);
            string pwd = System.Convert.ToString(passWord.Text);

            string xml = string.Empty;
            Uri url = new Uri("http://www.example.com/SR/Ch?mainEvent=Login&phNum="+phone +"&pass="+pwd);
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(result);

            JsonValue jsonList = JsonValue.Parse(result);
            Debug.WriteLine(jsonList);
}
```

The debug.Writeline(result) output is given below

ex:`[{"rV":1.2,"VerifiedUser":"test","ID":"1234","HD":"LI","Verify":"NEWUSER","key":"1234"}]`

2.I want to parse the data and diplay it in text box,how to do it?

the output for jsonlist is "Windows.Data.Json.JsonValue"

Comment: You should ask a detailed question with what you have done so far

Comment: @tarzanbappa:this is what i've done